# there's only one faucet in my house working but not the hot only cold please tell me what's the problem

Tags: plumbing

My faucet in the tub runs the cold side but not the hot but no other faucets run cold nor hot in the house what's going on

Comment: Frozen pipes most likely.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Did the hot water work up until recently? Is the tub backed up against an outside wall? Where are you located?